# Reverse transition on link effect

Tags: css, hyperlink, transition

I'm trying to get a specific effect for my links. I want my hyperlinks to have one color for text and another color for an underline. Then on hover, I want the colors to invert using an animation.

So far, I've been able to use just CSS to transition the two colors, but they both go from left to right. I want the underline to go from right to left.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
.entry-content a {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #009999;
    color: #111111;
    text-shadow: none;
} 

.entry-content a::before {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px 0;
    max-width: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #111111;
    color: #009999;
    content: attr(data-hover);
    -webkit-transition: max-width 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: max-width 0.2s;
    transition: max-width 0.2s;
}

.entry-content a:hover::before,
.entry-content a:focus::before {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Also, is there any way to achieve this result without using the "data-hover" attribute on my links? Or a way to just automatically fill in that attribute? It's just a pain to have to enter it manually for each link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. The parent needed to be set to relative instead of absolute, so that it can contain the absolute child element which is created by the ::before. Position the child absolute right and animate the width instead of max-width, works. And no you cannot do this without using data-hover in your css.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/ny597mfr/6/))

```css
.entry-content a {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #009999;
  color: #111111;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.entry-content a::before {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -2px;
  width: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #111111;
  color: #009999;
  content: attr(data-hover);
  -webkit-transition: width 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: width 0.2s;
  transition: width 0.2s;
}
.entry-content a:hover::before,
.entry-content a:focus::before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content" data-hover="A really long link">
  <a href="#">A really long Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked pretty nice. I think I'll have to end up going with some javascript though, because I don't want to have to use data-hover lol.

Comment: I was able to get [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MalachiDraven/jfpv8g9a/) from the source code of webdesignerdepot.com.